# mongoose: how to select multiple input on $filter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data like

```
game: {
        game: [{...},{...}],
        seminar: [{...}],
        event: [{...},{...},{...}],
      }
```

and the $filter

```
$filter: {
    input: "$game.game", <----- 
    as: "game",
    cond: {
      $and: [
        { $eq: ["$$game.game_type", game_type] },
        {
          $gte: [
            "$$game.game_info.game_time",
            start_date,
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

I want to do the query search for all of those three arrays and return to `game` field. But, I have no clue how to search them at the same time. How can I put the objects inside the `game`, `seminar` and `event` in one place to do the `$filter` search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6O4a9js5fm

Use [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      combinedArr: { // all the array values will be combined into 1 array
        $concatArrays: [
          "$game.game",
          "$game.seminar",
          "$game.event"
        ]
      },
      arr: {
        $concatArrays: [ // you'll get 1 array with individual objects
          [
            {
              game: "$game.game"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              seminar: "$game.seminar"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              event: "$game.event"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

You can directly use `concatArrays` like `input: { $concatArrays: [...] }` with `$filter`.